# When I switch from iPad to iPhone "view as" on xcode, one scene still looks like iPad

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

I was working on an app when I changed "view as" from iPad to iPhone and everything was fine except for one single view which kept the iPad view.

[image]

I tried to edit the constraints and all, but even tho when I run the app the app looks fine on iPhone, the "view as" keeps showing the scene as iPad.

Comment: Sorry, I took a screenshot of the problem: https://i.imgur.com/VRDOHPu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the view controller and open the size inspector tab on the right (Size Inspector).
[image]

Then make sure Simulated size is set to **Fixed**